# How to change locked file in external library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have problem. I need to edit one class from external library imported into my project, and this class is locked. How can i edit this class?

Thx

Comment: Import it as a module, or, even better, contribute to the open source if you think it is an improvement on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to import an external library as a module of your project, but what i prefer is to clone whole library and make appropriate changes as you need and then use it, or you can download whole ZIP file so it will allow you to manipulate and control everything.

Second option is better may be you can add more functionality and make existing thing even better.